# How to handle a large collection of time series in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, multidimensional-array, time-series

I have data that represents about 50,000 different 2-year monthly time series. What would be the most convenient and tidyverse-ish way to store that in R? I'll be using R to review each series, trying to extract characteristic features of their shapes.

Somehow a data frame with 50,000 rows and 24 columns (plus a few more for meta data) seems awkward, because the time axis is in the columns. But what else should I be using? A list of xts objects? A data frame with 50,000x24 rows? A three-dimensional matrix? I'm not really seeing anything obviously convenient, and my friend google hasn't found any great examples for me either. I imagine this means I'm overlooking the obvious solution, so maybe someone can suggest it. Any help?

Comment: The [`tsibble`](https://tsibble.tidyverts.org/) package might be helpful.

Comment: Thank you, it seems like a possibility.